# HTML Ouput from ashx handler

Tags: .net, ashx

When trying to write HTML ouput in my handler i get an error. How am i supposed to generate the output? Maybe your not supposed to be able to write output from here but send the output to a aspx page?

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.Write("test");     

    }
```

I get an "Syntax error. Unexpected token."

Comment: Sounds like you're using characters like a `'` in an unescaped way. Could you provide a sample where the error actually occurs?

Comment: This is an example! "Test" does not work. Can you confirm that it should work from a handler?

Comment: OK, sorry I was missing some HTML tags. I tried it out though, and yes it worked fine. Your error appears rather like a compile error than a runtime error. Is it?